# C: Weird behavior with spellchecking algorithm

Tags: c, spell-checking

I have an algorithm to receive words from a socket, then checks against a dictionary file if they are spelled correctly, and I'm experiencing some weird behavior with it. Basically, the spell checker will work correctly until I enter a word whose size (number of characters) is less than the size of the largest word previously entered. For example:
man OK

can OK

hello OK

can MISSPELLED.

It will also sometimes print out some seemingly random characters along with the word (when it's acting up, not when it's working properly), but I feel that that is caused by whatever the problem above is.
Here is the code for the spellcheck:

```
int i, ok;
char message[1024];
while((recv(socket, message, 1024, 0)) > 0){
  for(i = 0; i < WORD_COUNT; i++){
    if(strcasecmp(dict[i], message) == 0){
      printf(" OK");
      ok = 1;
      break;
   }
   if(!ok)
      printf(" MISSPELLED");
   puts("");
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `recv` will tell you how many bytes it wrote to `message`. (Also, what kind of socket?)

Comment: have you tried memsetting message back to all zeros after each spell check iteration?

Comment: Seems like you're not null terminating your buffer. Either use the return value from recv or just clear it to 0 every time before receiving.

Comment: @Ryan I'm not too familiar with socket programming, but I think the answer to your question is it's an IP socket (AF_INET family). The networking part of it seems to be working fine as I can connect and send words okay. Also, I am aware that recv returns the amount of bytes written, but how would that affect the spellchecking / message?

Comment: Would memsetting/clearing to zero just require a malloc()/calloc()/realloc() or is there more to it? I also tried setting message to "" and that didn't seem to work.

Comment: It seems like you're sending the word but not the zero that's necessary after it to terminate the string. The length of the word would tell you where to put that 0 to fix your problem.

Comment: are you sending `strlen(word)` bytes? That doesn't include the `NUL` terminator.

Comment: I'm using netcat to send, so I'm not entirely sure how that sends the words. Is there a way I could add the string terminator?

Comment: A packet sniffer like Wireshark will show you exactly what is being sent. Very useful for debugging network problems

Comment: you also need to initialize `ok = 0` at the start of the `while` loop ... or initialize it to 0 when you declare it and reset it to 0 in an `else`

Answer (score 1):

After you do a puts(""); in the while loop, add this line:

```
 memset(message, 0, sizeof(message));
```

Comment: wut this solution is like take a hammer in place of a needle.

Comment: what @Stargateur is so eloquently saying is that you really only need to memset however many bytes recv wrote for you

Comment: `while((ret = recv(socket, message, sizeof message - 1, 0)) > 0) {  message[ret] = '\0' }` end.

Comment: should check for ret == sizeof(message)

Comment: @Stargateur I think the euphemism you were looking for is "*using a sledgehammer for a fly-swatter...*" `:)`